# using jQuery bind event (mousedown+mouseover)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jQuery to bind when the mouse is over an element it perform an action. ? my code

```
$("div").bind('mouseover',function(){

  my_function();

});
```

Comment: It's not every clear what you're asking, here.

Comment: i think you are unableto get your code run may be you should use $("#element") in this way

Comment: You usually want to use `mouseenter` for this kind of thing, because `mouseout` has problems with bubbling

Comment: Didn't it work? Notice that [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is deprecated in favor of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) in newer jQuery versions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `mouseover`, not `mouseout` (obviously?)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#elementID").on('mouseover', function(event) {
        //code goes here
    });
```

You should use .on() instead of .bind();

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("seletor").bind('mouseover', function(event) {

 });
```